# Picking up document/Images from mobile device and show them into a list in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react native document picker library to upload documents to the server my code is working perfectly but the issue is i want to show list of these selected images/documents i am not sure how to perform that action here is my code....

Document Selection code:

```
pickMultiple() {
    try {
      DocumentPicker.pickMultiple({
      })
        .then(images => {
          this.setState({
            image: null,
            images: images
          });
          //console.log(images.length);
        })
        .catch(e => alert(e));
      } catch (err) {
        if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
          // User cancelled the picker, exit any dialogs or menus and move on
        } else {
          throw err;
        }
      }
  }
```

Form Uploading code:

```
SubmitProposal = async () => {
    const Uid = await AsyncStorage.getItem("projectUid");
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const { amount, Description, DurationListKnown, images } = this.state;
    console.log(
      amount,
      Description,
      DurationListKnown[0],
      images,
      params.job_id,
      images.length,
      Uid
    );
    const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('user_id' , Uid);
            formData.append('project_id' , params.job_id);
            formData.append('proposed_amount' , amount);
            formData.append('proposed_time' , DurationListKnown[0]);
            formData.append('proposed_content' , Description);
            formData.append('size' , images.length);


            //formData.append('proposal_files' , images);

            images.forEach((item, i) => {
                 // propertyData.description = this.props.description
                 var path = item.uri;
                 // var filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                 var filename = item.name;
                 formData.append("proposal_files"+i, {
                   uri: path,
                   type: item.type,
                   name: filename || `filename${i}.jpg`,
                 });
            });

            console.log(formData);
            fetch('https://...proposal/add_proposal',{
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },
                body: formData
              }).then(response => {
                if (response.status == "200") {
                  console.log(response);
                  this.showSuccessAlert();
                } else if (response.status == "203") {
                  console.log(response);
                  this.showAlert();
                } 
            }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify( error));
              });
  };
```

kindly help me about how can i show list of these images/documents

Comment: You mean you want to show them before you upload the image?

Comment: @hongdevelop yes i want to show before uploading

Comment: What is the value of images?

Comment: what do you mean by value? @hongdevelop

Comment: I want to see what the value of images has.

Comment: i am getting this kind of response
{size: 178201, name: "abstrakciya-wallpaper-1024x600-abstract-lines-3d-12741.jpg", type: "image/jpg", uri: "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/179"}

Comment: Please show me the results.

Comment: i am sending this data to server an it is uploading the images properly ... now i want to show the list in which i just want to show to name and type of each selected image/document thats it bro  @hongdevelop

Comment: You can use `this.state.images.map`